# How to call method in loop using vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I already call method in v-for, it works. But I get

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

How to solve this?

This is my code:

```
<tr v-for="(item,index) in all_data" :key="index">
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <td colspan="2">{{ toMakeLocalString(item.data_trx.total_penjualan) }}</td>
    <td>{{ roundDataPercentPerline(item.data_trx.total_penjualan,all_data_trx.penjualan) }}</td>
                            
     {{ resetVal() }}
     <template v-for="(itemBodyJum,indexBodyJum) in arrHeader">
         <template v-if="itemBodyJum == item.data_provider[incrementI].denom">
         <td :key="indexBodyJum+item.data_provider[incrementI].jumlah_trx">{{ toMakeLocalString(item.data_provider[incrementI].jumlah_trx) }}</td>
         {{ incVal(incrementI) }}
      </template>
      <template v-else>
         <td :key="indexBodyJum+index">0</td>
      </template> 
</tr>
```

My method:

```
incVal(val, flagcond) {
   console.log(this.flagInc+'---1')
   if(this.flagInc == false) {
      this.flagInc = true
      console.log(this.flagInc+'---2')
      this.incrementI = val + 1
   }
},
resetVal() {
  this.flagInc = false
  this.incrementI=0
}
```

Comment: You should avoid mutating the same data that is being used in the V-FOR cycle.

Comment: @IVOGELOV can you give me example related my question?

Comment: Don't call function in template. Instead handle all logic in script before displaying.

Comment: @AJT82 i want make increment variable but that variable back 0 again if the index loop in <tr> get next number. can you give me example about that? thanks

Comment: Can you provide a working CodeSandbox example to demonstrate your issue ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV this is my CodeSandbox link, https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-shape-715er?file=/src/main.js. just click preview to show result and warning messge

Comment: I just mean that do not call `incVal` in template. Instead, as it seems you want to do some calculation when form is submitted. So make the calculation in script on form submit, store it in a property/variable and show that in template.

Comment: I don't know what incVal is for, but anyway handle it as a variable. I see that you are also calling several other functions in template, I would suggest to avoid it.The more you have going on in your code... it can affect the performance when the functions are called so often.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you change the `incrementI` variable during the `V-FOR`. Try to use something else instead - e.g. `indexBodyJum` or `indexBodyPen`.

Comment: I dont use indexBodyJum or indexBodyPen because that variable just increment. what i want is the variable increment if suitable conditions. e.g v-if="itemBodyJum == item.data_provider[increamentI].denom"

Comment: The reason for the warning is that you change the `incrementI` variable - if you want to get rid of the warning you need to prepare your data arrays outside of the cycle and then inside the cycle only read data without modifying it.

Comment: are there other alternatives for increment variable in loop like another language, e.g php in vue?

Comment: Vue is different from PHP and other languages - just like SQL is different from Java and other languages. One alternative is to get the data for template from a computed property - and inside the computed property you can increment as many variables as you need.